# Unable to install library in virtual environment

Tags: python, pip

I'm not able to install any library in virtual environment. It gives me the following error:

```
venv) D:\python projects>pip install pandas
Cannot open D:\python projects\venv\Scripts\pip-script.py
```

However if i get out of venv and try to install it globally it gets finished without any error.

but I don't know the reason of the error. Another question is that if i have to upgrade the pip version, do i have to upgrade it separately first globally then in my venv?   Also Is there any way to use globally installed library in venv?

Comment: Using space in file/dir name is like asking for troubles

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by rebuilding my venv, a bit destructive but you can pip freeze >  for the packages your using before hand then pip install -r  to restore them to your new venv